# Сделать круг без четверти с контентом внутри

Tags: html, css

Как сотворить что-то на подобии этого?

[image: Как должно выглядеть]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.wrap {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/300/);
}

.content_svg_arc {
  width: 180px;
  height: 195px;
  top: 8px;
  position: absolute;
}

.content_text {
  border-radius: 55px 0 0 20px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 60px;
  top: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 45px;
  font: bold 15px/1em 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-shadow: -1px -2px 0px white, 1px -2px 0px white, 1px 2px 0px white, -1px 2px 0px white;
}

.color {
  color: #00c7c7;
}

.big {
  font: bold 5em sans-serif;
}

.text_second_line {
  font: bold 1em/1em sans-serif;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <svg class="content_svg_arc">
    <path d="M160 29 A 90 90 55 1 0 180 130"
        stroke-width="7"  stroke="#ffffff"  fill="none"/>
    <path d="M160 29 A 90 90 55 1 0 180 130"
        stroke-width="3"  stroke="#00c7c7"  fill="none"/>
  </svg>
  <div class="content_text">
    <div>
      <span>более</span>
      <span class="color big">10</span>
      <span class="color">лет</span>
    </div>
    <span class="text_second_line">
      успешной работы
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Пример

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.circle {
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px auto;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 2px solid #00f;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.circle__text{
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute; top: 15px; right: -50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
    <div class="circle__text">
        Сделать круг без четверти с контентом внутри
    </div>
</div>
```